# iOS BugSense Integration Issue

Tags: ios, bugsense

The BugSense SDK integrated in my APp is latest & is 3.6. Here is the sample code to initialize bugsense in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[BugSenseController sharedControllerWithBugSenseAPIKey:@"YOUR-API-KEY" 
                    userDictionary:nil 
                    sendImmediately:YES];
```

The BugSense dashboard indicates that new sessions are being created in the 'insights' section.

[image: Sessions]

However, sessions & unique users indicated in the header do not increase, neither are crashes being reported.

[image: sessions]

I have added a manual crash in app, by calling a method after 20 seconds.

```
 NSArray *myArray = @[[NSNull null], [NSNull null], [NSNull null], 
                      [NSNull null], [NSNull null]];
NSLog(@"%@", myArray[98]);
```

I am testing by archiving the build & using iTunes to sync the build instead of running directly on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried everything I could, compared configurations to another project, tried custom exception handlers but nothing worked. In the end, I had to recreate the whole project and add files again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using free version of the bugsense?

I am using paid version of the bugsense (Indie). Free version only has 7-days data retention while Indie version has 30-days data retention. I just checked my bugsense and I calculated the number. Both the header and also the dashboard have almost equal number of sessions.

I believe that the number of session on header (on your account) is based on sessions within the last 7 days. But the number of my session is based on the last 30 days.

But, the session under the dashboard is based on 30 days period. Therefore, your number of session does not add up. But, my app sessions is almost the same. I can not 100% confirm on this. If you want to confirm 100%, I think you may ask the bugsense support on the number.

[image]

Comment: Hm.... Then I have no idea on the data discrepancy on your side. I guess you will have to ask the bugsense support to understand better. They should know better.